# Insert Zero Before and After a data point

Tags: text-processing, sed, numeric-data

I need a script that inserts a zero before and after each data point. I am trying to do this in Ubuntu.

Example:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

What I need:

```
0
1
0
0
2
0
0
3
0
0
4
0
0
5
0
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{ print "0" ORS $0 ORS "0" }' < input
```

or:

```
awk '{ print "0"; print $0; print "0" }' < input
```

To me, that's a straight-forward implementation of "print a zero before and after every line" in awk.

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU sed, **i**nsert a zero and **a**ppend a zero at every line:

```
sed -e 'i\0' -e 'a\0' data
```

Ex.

```
$ printf '%d\n' 1 2 3 | sed -e 'i\0' -e 'a\0'
0
1
0
0
2
0
0
3
0
```

Comment: It might happen that sed complains: `sed: \<newline> missing after command: i\0`. In bash, this might work: `sed -e $'i\\\n0' -e $'a\\\n0'`

Answer (score 2):

With a single GNU `sed` invocation:

```
seq 5 |sed 's/.*/0\n&\n0/'
```

The same in standard `sed` syntax:

```
seq 5 |sed 's/.*/0\
&\
0/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GNU `sed` to do that. `^` to match line begin and `$` for end:

```
sed 's/^/0\n/; s/$/\n0/'
```

```
printf "1\n2\n3\n" | sed 's/^/0\n/; s/$/\n0/'
0
1
0
0
2
0
0
3
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard `sed`:

```bsh
sed -e 's/^/0\
/'  -e 's/$/\
0/' file
```

This inserts `0` followed by a newline character at the start and preceded by a newline character at end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne 'put "0\n$_\n0";'
```

OR

```
raku -ne 'put qq[0\n$_\n0];'
```

OR EVEN:

```
raku -ne 'put "0\n", $_, "\n0";'
```

Sample Input:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Sample Output:

```
0
1
0
0
2
0
0
3
0
0
4
0
0
5
0
```

This is pretty straightforward, with the Raku `$_` topic variable being appropriately decorated before-and-after. Since `~` tilde is used in Raku for string concatenation, the substitution can be written `"0\n" ~ $_ ~ "\n0"` if that's more readable (also brackets/parens can be added if desired).

Some of the niceties you get by using Raku is simple expansion to more complicated substitutions--for example--adding a conditional to remove blank lines:

Retain blank lines:

```
raku -ne 'put ["0\n" ~ $_ ~ "\n0"];'
```

Remove blank lines:

```
raku -ne 'put ["0\n" ~ $_ ~ "\n0"] if .chars;'
```

https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

With `paste`:

```
$ seq 5 > file
$ :|paste -d '0\n\n' - - file - -
0
1
0
0
2
0
0
3
0
0
4
0
0
5
0
```

That's pasting an empty input, here as `-` meaning stdin where stdin is the output of the null command `:` for brevity several times with `file`, with `0`, `\n` and `\n` (and looping) in turn as separator.

To process stdin instead of a `file`, you can use `/dev/null` instead as empty input:

```
$ seq 3 | paste -d '0\n\n' /dev/null /dev/null - /dev/null /dev/null
0
1
0
0
2
0
0
3
0
```